# Why is my browser not setting the cookie it receives from my backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, authentication, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie that contains a jwt token after a successful login to the client but when the browser receives it, it doesn't get set. I know that the response contains a cookie is received because part of the response headers is "Set-Cookie".

This is my code from the backend that sets the cookie:

```js
res.cookie('jwtToken', token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'None',
      maxAge: 3600000
    })
```

Here's the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: jwtToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY1Zjg0NjFhMzYwZmU3MjlmZjIxMzVmYiIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsImlhdCI6MTcxMDc3Mjk2OCwiZXhwIjoxNzEwNzc2NTY4fQ.oV49HPeJZtk3Vsc__xTecU8yWbcD_QJdCubtD3Ppgs0; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 18 Mar 2024 15:42:48 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 294
ETag: W/"126-2EE1HbPx1KFS/evxa+82EKfejss"
Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2024 14:42:48 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Some details that might be important:

1. I'm using express for the backend and react the frontend.
2. My backend and frontend have different ports but I have made sure to setup CORS properly along with a `credentials: include` option.
3. I have the cookie-parser middleware setup to enable me to set cookies.
4. I check for the cookie through another route that is supposed to parse the cookie from the req headers however the it always ends up being undefined. (I've made sure to include credentials when making the request)

Initially I though the problem could be related to my frontend and backend not being ran over https so I have created certificates for it using mkcert however this does not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot use JavaScript to retrieve the cookie "jwtToken" after receiving a response?

Comment: @neillee I mean that when I check if the cookie exists by making a separate request and parsing it, the cookie doesn't exist or is undefined.

Something like this:

const token = req.cookies.jwtToken
console.log('Token:', token);

----
Token is always undefined

Comment: @Kobra What would the problem be?